# Configuring views to display all book-pages inside a book, from whenever you are inside the book

Tags: views

Configuring views to display all book-pages inside a book, from whenever you are inside the book.

Is this possible? If so please advice the way to do it.

The contexual filter of **All sub nodes of this book page** creates an error soon as I relate it to any position or Node ID on a book-hierarchy.
When set **view all pages** instead - other books page is viewed together with the pages I want to display.

(The  Relationships here is set to **top level book** with **Require this relationship**)

Answer (score 1):

I did found the reason why it not work (as it should), it's probably a bug at the "filter criteria", who not where working with setting of *Book depth*. 
I am lucky because I had different content-types on each level of the book.
And when trash away the book depth *filter criteria*  I could set filtering on the *Content type* instaed, and all works out as I wanted.
So this problem is solved,now I can **display all book-pages inside a book, from whenever you are inside the book** without any problem.